# How can I write unit test using Jest if I'm using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

```
setTimeout(()=>{
var sortBtn = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.clsname'));
for(const item of sortBtn){
item.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    dataCollector('somestring',e.target);
  })
}
 },1000);
```

Data collector is a function that is performing some processing based on click

Comment: From the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks

Comment: I'm not able to figure out can you please help for above code how can I track click in jest after 1s